# Jquery 1.8.1 - Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in false with JScrollpane

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, error-handling, jscrollpane

I used jquery 1.6.1 with plugin JSrollpane, and then I pluged the newest 1.8.1 version of jquery.
And it gives an error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in false

Maybe somebody knows, what is this mean? And what should i do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you update the new version of jquery and mousewheel.js?

Comment: Yes. JQuery 1.8.1 and mousewheel.js 3.0.6